# Can I use MySQL-SERVER tunning variables in MYSQL CLUSTER?

Tags: performance, mysql-cluster, configuration

When tunning **MySQL-SERVER** for best performance, the edition is done down `my.cnf` file.

Such as:

```
max_connections = 500
wait_timeout = 600
sort_buffer_size = 2M
```

Can I improve **MySQL CLUSTER** performance with those editable variables down `[mysqld]` tag of `config.ini` of mgmt node or `my.cnf` of ndbd node?

The main reason of this question is that I'm getting **ERROR 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** when importing a 1.2 G .sql file. I can't find any solution to this refering to **MySQL CLUSTER** so I want to try with the `wait_timeout`variable, but I don know if it's compatible with.

Will it accept those variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all this tuning variables are described in [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html)